# Basic Swift Aid

Tags: swift

and thanks in advance for any help.

I, being the rookie coder I am, decided to make a super basic "you put in a value, and receive a preset back" deal. Literally, if you say Alabama, you get preset text. But I encountered some trouble in setting up both these variables(50 state names) and getting the UI to actually connect to this. After some searching around, I couldn't really find any help, at least in layman terms :)

Essentially, I aim to allow the user to put in a state name, and the app gives them a value. Any explanations/basic frame work of how to do it is greatly appreciated

If it helps at all, I had started with this?

```
class States {

    var Alabama: String = "Zone 6b to 8b"
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: An enum seems like a better fit for this than a class.

Comment: Something closer to this? Not sure how to integrate the "values associated with each state.                                                                 enum States :String{
case Alabama
case Alaska
}

Comment: Why don’t you start [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/151741/macos-development-beginners-part-1) and worry about your states later.

Comment: @trees For a simple name-to-string mapping, you can do something like: `enum State: String { case alabama = "Zone 6b to 8b" case alaska = "Zone whatever to whatever" etc. }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Good call. I'd also recommend: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: Been there, just wondered about this case. Thank you for all the help so far   @CharlesSrstka   EDIT: any ideas on setting up the "if (state) then print(value)" statements?

Answer (score 1):

This is never going to work:

```
var Alabama: String = "Zone 6b to 8b"
```

...because you cannot easily *introspect* the States object to find its `Alabama` variable. A string `"Alabama"` is not a variable property name. They live in two different worlds, and never the twain shall meet (except for key-value coding but let's ignore that for now).

To associate the string `"Alabama"` with another string in such a way that you can look up the other string by using the string `"Alabama"`, use a *Dictionary*. That is what a Dictionary *is*.

Comment: Understood. Any opinion on the enum solution/ UI integration?

Comment: This is not a good venue for opinions. The point is simply that what you can look up with the string `"Alabama"` is another string `"Alabama"`, not a variable name.

Comment: @trees It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to look up things by compile-time names, as in the example in your question, use an enum. If you are trying to look things up via strings, the Dictionary is the best choice, as matt says.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yeah, I was trying get values from searching compile-time names. However, this isn't for my benefit so to speak, I'm intending for the user to enter the search.

Comment: @trees In that case, the dictionary is probably the way to go. Please do read the document I linked to in the comments on the OP; it will help you understand Swift's basic built-in data structures a lot better.